# Creating a debian package for my python application from a system running fedora

Tags: python, debian, fedora

I have created a small python application to be used internally in my organization. I wrote the code on my primary development machine running Fedora 17 and I would like to create a .deb in order to make it easy for my colleagues to install my program.

Is it possible to create debian packages for python application from a system running fedora? If yes, how?

Comment: Why don't you want to create an RPM rather than a deb package?

Comment: simple, because I have to run the program on a debian machine later.

Answer (score 1):

It would be possible to do it manually, but it would be quicker and less painful to create it on a debian-based distribution (you could use a virtual machine if you don't want to install one)

Following [this guide](http://ghantoos.org/2008/10/19/creating-a-deb-package-from-a-python-setuppy/) is probably the best way forward if you're already using an `install.py`.

Answer (score 1):

Create an rpm package, give it to your Debian users and tell them to convert the rpm to a Debian package using alien on their Debian box.